# What does it mean for an object to be at rest?

Tags: calculus, kinematics

I understand that "at rest" means that the velocity is equal to 0 (v(t)=0) but I am having a hard time creating a definitive answer surrounding the question.

Comment: Please specify what your actual question ?

Comment: What exactly is your definition of a "definitive answer"?

Comment: When you clarify the question, also please make sure to highlight the mathematics that is involved; "what does it mean for an object to be at rest" sounds like a question about physics, not mathematics.

Comment: @AakashKumar Unfortunately that was the entirety of the question given

Comment: @GregoryGrant Basically being able to explain what it means for an object to be at rest while incorporating how v(t) = 0

Comment: It only makes sense to discuss being at rest with respect to some fixed reference frame.

Comment: Velocity is frame dependent . If you are even moving a observer can claim that you are in rest . Please specify frame .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An object's velocity can only be measured relative to another object.

For example, suppose you are on a bus.

You are not moving on the bus, but the bus itself is moving.  Therefore, you can say you are at rest "relative" to the bus, but you are moving relative to the ground/pavement.